# DirectX Color: Why can't it be a float?

Tags: c++, directx

In my vertex declaration I can use various data types for color.  Including:

- INT
- DWORD
- D3DCOLOR

I can't however use a float, it causes my shader to get the incorrect value.

I know an float is 4 bytes and so are all the other datatype I listed.  So why does a float not work and the others do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How would a single float represent the 4 `(A,R,G,B)` components? If you wonder how int does it, it packs 4 bytes within its 32bit (4 bytes) value.

Comment: Well technically it *would* be possible to do the same with a `float` so that doesn't really answer OP's question.

Comment: @Cicada: Is not that simple, the binary layout of a `float` is a bit more complicated than that... Yes, it is possible, but by reinterpreting the memory of a `float` as an `int` at both sides so its pretty much useless

Comment: What I mean is that your answer isn't the reason why floats don't work as colors.

Comment: @Cicada, I don't see your answer yet? I think K-ballo has it right. An integer is a natural representation of packed bytes, while a float is not.

Comment: @MarkRansom A `float` certainly is 4-bytes wide like an `int` is and certainly can be used to pack 4 bytes together. Something in DirectX must be doing arithmetic on the float (other than on the bit level, eg `+`), that's why the value is wrong, I believe.